# setOnItemLongClickListener LIST VIEW

Tags: android, firebase, listview

[image: imagen del código fuente]

Quiero eliminar un ítem de mi *ListView*, pero no puedo. Este es el código que tengo para remover un ítem.

Comment: Hola por favor, añade tu código en formato de texto

Comment: Define "no puedo". ¿Te da un error? ¿Ejecuta pero no elimina el elemento? Y sube el código como texto. Además, añade la definición del arrayList, del adapter y de list_direccion.